# I cant connect my device to localhost but on emulator work

Tags: localhost, device

I connect to my localhost with my emulator (Genymotion) with an ip (192.168.2.103) 
for down load a JSON.
is the ip of my pc and localhost too;
All ok, but when a try to connect with my device don't work.
the full Url is "http://192.168.2.103/product/connect_get_all_products.php"
Use Wamp for localserver

The webserver running in local on pc ip: at the Server: mysql wampserver (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)

My emulator work on the ip : 192.168.56.101:5555 (default ip for genymotion emulator) and it's downlaod the file without problem

The ip of my pc in localweb is : 192.168.2.103 (take by ipconfig)

My device is connect via USB but The wifi is enable (i think the problem is here)

I try to use apache HttpResponse an my status line is 403 "forbidden"

turn off all firewall but nothing

Comment: please be a little more detailed. Where is the webserver running? What are the IP addresses of the emulator/server/computer(s) involved? Specify what isn't working and what error message you get (server not found? Resource not found?).

Comment: I bet you 5$ against one that this is a firewall problem.